# Why can't we use UNION ALL and ORDER BY together in SQL

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 LEN(CITY),CITY
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LEN(CITY),CITY;
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP 1 LEN(CITY),CIYT
    FROM STATION
    ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC,CITY DESC;
```

Comment: I removed in inappropriate database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: `ORDER BY` goes at the end of **all** your statements. Also you are terminating your statement and starting a new one with `UNION ALL`.

Comment: As @Lamu said but terminating **because of the semicolon** before `UNION ALL`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Thanks for pointing out the errors...I will keep them in mind the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY`, when using a `UNION ALL` goes at the end of the entire statement, not at the end of each one. You also have a statement terminator (`;`) after your first query, meaning you have a `SELECT TOP(1)` query followed by a further query that starts with `UNION ALL`.

You need to use subqueries here and then `UNION` those:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) LEN(CITY) AS CITYLEN, CITY
      FROM STATION
      ORDER BY LEN(CITY),CITY) S
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) LEN(CITY) AS CITYLEN, CITY
      FROM STATION
      ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC,CITY DESC) S
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database supports `TOP` (which most of the original tags do not), you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM ((SELECT TOP (1) LEN(CITY) AS LEN, CITY
       FROM STATION
       ORDER BY LEN(CITY), CITY
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP (1) LEN(CITY), CITY
       FROM STATION
       ORDER BY LEN(CITY) DESC, CITY DESC
      )
     ) c;
```

Of course, semicolons are not allowed in the middle of a query either, so that is another problem with your query.

Comment: This has the same problem my query initially had, you need to alias the columns in the subqueries, or you'll get an error.